# C++ Visual Studio 2010 "Unable to start Program"

Tags: c++, dll

I've been looking arund and i can't find the problem for this. Whenever i try to debug my project, i get this error

```
Unable to start program 'C:/Users/.../project/.dll'
```

All i did was create a new application than put this

```
// This is the main DLL file.


#include "stdafx.h"

#include "asddsa.h"

/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Arhowk
 *
 * Created on March 22, 2013, 10:15 PM
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
using namespace std;
void main()
{
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;  
  cout << "Welcome to C++ Programming" << endl;
}
```

any help? I can provide more debug info if needed, but cant find any. Running VS2010 Express on a W7 x64 machine

Answer (score 5):

1. You shoud create an exe project like "Win32 Console Application"
2. "C:/Users/.../project/.dll" looks wrong, Right click your project, select "Properties", check  "General->TargetName", "Debugging->Command" and "Linker->General->Output File"

Answer (score 4):

When you created your project, what type did you create? It looks like you created a DLL project. DLLs can't be ran directly, you need to have an exe that will load one or more DLLs.

If you create an exe project, you should be able to run it directly to test your code.